# Call Center Income halal or Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, money

Assalamualaikum I work in a call center, and our job is to make a fake Facebook id by using Foreign names like David,Jake,etc living in USA but I live in Pakistan. What we do is we join groups of their Respective cities in US and we post about our services like Car Detailing,Duct Cleaning, etc. however we don't scam them, we do provide services to customers but we do lie about our identity such as names and where do we live. Is this source of income halal?

Comment: Why would you think lying for money would ever be okay in Islam?

Comment: @goldPseudo from the question, it is not lying for money, but for opportunity, if this isn't just another lie. I also wonder who someone residing in Pakistan can do duct cleaning in USA.

Comment: @goldPseudo there is also the aspect of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqiyya , not in the literal sense, of course, as the question is not *primarily* about hiding ones faith.

Comment: @GyroGearloose  no, why would I lie to you. I just get customers by having fake identity and when I book their appointment I send it to the guy who is living in USA and then he goes at their home and does the service

Comment: So, you, yourself, live in Pakistan, but are doing, some kind of, taqiyya, for your people living in the US, hoping they will get called for service if the customer knows them as *Ben* rather than *Abdul*?